# Could it ever make sense to use megahertz as a unit of energy?

Tags: terminology, energy

I'm reading Nnedi Okorafor's book *Noor*.  In it, the author describes a character who has invented a way to transmit energy through the air using some kind of light wave.  OK, I get it, it's sci-fi, I can go along with that.  But then this character compared how much of the energy she sent with how much was received half a mile away.... She was overjoyed to see that...

> 5 MHz was received.  She hadn't lost a single megahertz.

Is there some other way to interpret this?  Because that doesn't make a lick of sense.  Hertz describes the *frequency* of something periodic, such as a sound wave, but it does not describe how much *energy* has been stored.  Right?

Your thoughtful answer might help me pick this book up again, but for now I'm feeling pretty done with it.  Relatedly, if there is no way that hertz could be used to describe an amount of energy, my question should be "How could a sci-fi editor not know what a joule is?"

Comment: "Hadn't lost a single <insert unit here>" is a common colloquial phrasing, suggesting a very casual tone - so casual that the speaker might intentionally use an incorrect unit as a mild joke.

Comment: This is fun: https://youtu.be/KmfdeWd0RMk

Answer (score 5):

For electromagnetic (EM) quanta—that is, photons—the frequency and the energy are directly proportional, so that to specify the frequency is to specify the energy (and the wavelength) of each photon.  If the loss mechanism is through some sort of scattering that would reduce the frequency and thus the energy of each photon, it **might** make sense to discuss the energy loss in terms of megahertz, but it would still be highly unusual. Moreover, in actual EM transmissions, the primary loss mechanism is photons sent but not received at all, not frequency change.

The total energy transmitted, of course, is the product of the energy per photon (or the average energy if the transmission is not on a single frequency) and the total number of photons. The power is the amount of energy per unit time.

I fear that this reads to me like someone using technical terminology who does not understand it, much like Han Solo's comment that he made the "Kessel run" in "less than twelve parsecs".  A parsec is a unit of distance, not time, but that statement implies speed and thus time measurements. Megahertz are indeed normally a unit of frequency, not energy or power. This passage would have made much more sense if a unit of energy (such as joules or ergs) or of power (such as watts) had been used instead.

Comment: Under the right circumstances, (e.g. when studying atomic physics), it is routine to refer to energies in units of megahertz or gigahertz.  However, the scenario described in the question does not seem to belong to such circumstances.

Comment: @Buzz Even when studying atomic physics, isn't it far more common to give energy in electron volts, not mHz?

Comment: No, not necessarily.  It is most common to describe transitions in terms of whatever the actually measured quantity is in an experiment.  For optical transitions (with energies in the eV range), what one actually measures is the wavelength of the light used to stimulate a transition, so those energy differences are described in terms of a wavelength.  For lower-energy transitions, the transition is stimulated by a radio-frequency oscillating voltage, and the energies are thus most commonly quoted as frequencies (e.g. approximately 1 420 405 751.768 Hz) for the hydrogen hyperfine line.

Comment: There is a very solid reason for these conventions, actually.  If you want to convert the energy from GHz to eV, the conversion factor depends on things like the electron charge e and ħ, which have experimental uncertainties of their own—uncertainties which may be substantially larger than the uncertainty of the frequency measurement.

Answer (score -2):

### Nnedi Okorafor Has the Science Correct (even if my math might not be)

Given:

1. Einstein’s theory of special relativity for the equivalence of mass and energy: E = mc^2
2. de Broglie equation for electromagnetic radiation energy: E = h * c / λ
3. Planck’s equation for the energy of a photon: E = h * v

c = speed of light: 299,792,458 m/s
h = the Planck constant: 6.62607015·10⁻³⁴ J·s

λ is the wavelength 
v is the frequency

Solve for equivalency, joules can be expressed as Hz:
(1 J)/h = 1.509 190 311(67) × 10³³ Hz.

Yes, for electromagnetic radiation, energy is directly proportional to frequency, measured in Hertz.

This energy measured in Hz can then be converted to other measures of energy such as barrels of oil equivalent, or of course Joules.

Comment: The thing is, the number of hertz in an electromagnetic wave (its frequency) is not directly proportional to its energy, which is in fact proportional to the scaled sum of the squares of its amplitudes (electric and magnetic). A loss of energy over distance due to absorption in a medium will thus generally not involve a change in the frequency (if it did, Wi-Fi antenna standardization would have serious problems). Also, note that you have a factor of *h* in your equivalence, indicating that it is not really an equivalence between units.

Comment: The factor, h, is a constant; Planck’s constant: 6.62607015·10⁻³⁴ J·s.

Comment: Because that constant has units, the equation that you have written is not an equivalence *between units*.

Comment: Because it’s different measures of energy, which can be measured as a function of kg, m, and seconds _or_ as a function of wavelength, or as a function of several other units such as US equivalent barrels of oil.